# MySQL Join horizontal with vertical table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE person {
    id INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE
}

CREATE TABLE field {
    id INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
}

CREATE TABLE fieldPerson {
    id INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    fieldId INT(11) UNSIGNED,
    personId INT(11) UNSIGNED,
    value VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (fieldId) REFERENCES field(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (personId) REFERENCES person(id)
}
```

This is well summed up. Basically we have the default fields `name` and `email`, and we have the option to create custom fields, such as `telephone`, `address`, etc.
We can have **n** fields. I'm trying to figure out a way to do a `SELECT` query that returns all fields without making use of subqueries or extra work outside the database (it's ok using joins though).

Example (telephone is a custom field):

```
TABLE person:

id    name       email
1     Test 1     test1@gmail.com

---- 

TABLE field:

id    name
1     telephone
2     address

----

TABLE fieldPerson:

id    fieldId    personId    value
1     1          1           +1 555 555 555
2     2          1           First St.

----   

RESULTING QUERY

personId   name          email            telephone       Address
1          Test 1        test1@gmail.com  +1 555 555 555  First St.
```

Is that possible?

Thanks.

EDIT:

If not possible, you may suggest a optimal solution using subqueries, only with SQL though.

Comment: But I guess JOIN is inevitable.

Comment: Sure, JOIN is ok, I just don't want to rely on subqueries `(SELECT ...) AS ...`

Comment: No, field only has a name column. I need to gather the value of it and use as a column name.

Comment: update your question adding a realistic data sample

Comment: @scaisEdge just updated.

Comment: How about PIVOT?

Comment: @BartoszSiemasz Pivot in mysql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT p.*
     , group_concat(CASE f.name WHEN 'telephone' THEN fp.value END) telephone
     , group_concat(CASE f.name WHEN 'address'   THEN fp.value END) address
  FROM person p
  JOIN field f
    LEFT JOIN fieldPerson fp
      ON    fp.personId = p.id
        AND fp.fieldId = f.id
  GROUP BY p.id
```

Answer (score 3):

So, depending on how much control you have over the query generation, if you can generate the `SELECT` columns in the same order as the `PRIMARY KEY` of `field`, you could try the following. I'm envisioning something where you know there's 2 keys in `field`, and what they are in advance (from an earlier query?).

```
SELECT fp.personId,p.name,p.email,fp.value as telephone,fp2.value as Address 
    FROM fieldPerson fp INNER JOIN person p ON p.id = fp.personId 
                        INNER JOIN field f ON f.id = fp.fieldId 
                        INNER JOIN fieldPerson fp2 
    WHERE fp.fieldId = 1 and fp2.fieldId = 2;
```

This gives me the result, given the sample data in the question:

```
personId | name   | email           | telephone      | Address   |
       1 | Test 1 | test1@gmail.com | +1 555 555 555 | First St. |
```

This hinges on the notion that you've avoided the sub-query by doing an initial query earlier to know the arbitrary fields defined in the `fields` table. You didn't specify how dynamic this table is expected to be, so this may not be an unreasonable simplifying assumption to make.

Barring that, you can try something like:

```
SELECT fp.personId,p.name,p.email,fp.value as telephone,fp2.value as Address 
    FROM fieldPerson fp INNER JOIN person p ON p.id = fp.personId 
                        INNER JOIN field f ON f.id = fp.fieldId 
                        INNER JOIN fieldPerson fp2 
    WHERE fp.fieldId != fp2.fieldId LIMIT 1,1;
```

This gives me the same output without having to know the field id numbers, but I do need to know the names of the fields to generate the column names. The `LIMIT` is there to remove one of the `JOIN` products, and has a distinctly unholy feeling to it, I agree. I feel like there's not too much advantage to approach 2, since you have to know the column names anyways.

I would agree with @Mojtaba, however, that if you can't live with a pre-query to know the dynamic field names and ids, then I believe you're going to have to put sub-`SELECT` statements in there to pull those at query time.